# IIS playing up- not allowing external IP access

Tags: windows, iis, ip, port-forwarding, xampp

Ok I have IIS fully working, on my internal IP.

However, no matter what I do, it seems to ignore external IP access.

I have forwarded port 80 onto my internel IP, and it works with XAMPP. After closing XAMPP and booting IIS (IIS makes it a lot easier to upload Visual Studio stuff that updates), it doesn't allow the access.

Comment: You are sure you are not being blocked by a firewall?

Comment: Well AVG seems to have no firewall. I'll disable my windows firewall see if that helps.

Comment: Wow, I'm depressed now. It's my firewall, but I have no clue how to allow the service through since it doesn't show up on the list and I have no idea where the file is located since view file location isn't showing on the right click menu.

Comment: Found. Which exe do I allow through? Inetmanager.exe, appcmd.exe, there's quite a few.

Comment: Open port 80 on your firewall and it should work.... I am making this the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your firewall is open....

Check your windows firewall as well as your hardware firewalls....

If you turn off your windows firewall and it works it is most certainly that....

You must open port 80 on the windows firewall to allow HTTP traffic through.

[For windows 7](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-7/open-a-port-in-windows-7s-firewall/)

[For Xp](http://www.no-ip.com/support/guides/routers/configuring_windows_xp_firewall.html)

You did not specify this was on a windows server please let us know if it is and I will link the appropriate guide for the Firewall

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you can ping the external IP, also make sure that the firewall (physical or Windows Firewall) isn't blocking port 80 (and 443 for SSL).  And make sure that you added the correct bindings to the site for the external IP. Here's a [quick video walkthrough](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2011/01/29/understanding-iis-bindings.aspx).

Comment: canyouseeme.org found the port open. The bindings are set to dafault (*). As I said, XAMPP worked fine, but IIS isn't.